# Is there any method or idea that can select characters from a string at indices which are multiple of given 'n' to get the result string?

Tags: java, string

If I have this string

```
String str="characters";
```

the  result would like following

```
result="caatr";
```

what I have done is selecting char by char from the given string until we get the result. The chars are selected at indices which are multiples of given n. Example: if n=2, the relevant indices to be selected are 0, 2, 4 ... and for n = 3, the indices are 0, 3, 6...

I have solved it in two ways and are almost the same but is there any other ways?

```
char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
String s="";
for(int i=0;i<str.length();i=i+n)
    s=s+arr[i]+"";
```

the other one is

```
String result = "";
for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i = i + n) 
    result = result + str.charAt(i);
```

Comment: Whats the issue/error/problem? Looks like you are trying to remove alternate characters and not "unknown" characters. Also, what is the value of `n` in `i = i + n`?

Comment: The second technique should be slightly faster. You shouldn't notice any difference for small strings though. For long strings, what will kill the performance is the constant creation of new temporary strings. Use a StringBuilder to avoid that.

Comment: so basically: all the chars, except for those on odd locations in the original String?

Comment: Yes, sometime one by one if n=2 the index that should removed 0, 2, 4 ...and so on , if n=3 the index would be 0,3, 6 ...

Comment: String d = ""; for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i = i+2){ d = str.charAt(i); }

Comment: @Stultuske ,your solution is the same my second solution, I am looking for another solution

Comment: then the question is: why. there is no default implementation for something like this, nor would it make any sense to implement it. That way is simple, easy, and about as good as it gets

Comment: StringBuilder is probably more efficient since you're not creating  a new string for each loop iteration.

Comment: @nicomp indeed, but it doesn't change the actual way of working

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(getResultOf("characters"));
}

private static String getResultOf(String input) {
    boolean skip = false;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char ch : input.toCharArray()) {
        if (!skip) {
            sb.append(ch);
        }
        skip = !skip;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your try, but your solution is for one case when n=2

Comment: @BobakerMadi as already said in the comments: your second way is the obvious, natural, efficient way (provided you use a StringBuilder instead of using string concatenation) to do what you want. We can try finding funny alternative solutions, but there's really no point: they will all be less readable, or less efficient, or less generic, than the one you have. So, what are you looking for, exactly?

Comment: I post this question to find if there is any method for example str.remove()
I tried to use replace method but the problem is in each time the size of string  reduced and the index for each chars has also changed.

Comment: So, you got your answer: the only problem with your second way is that it doesn't use a StringBuilder. Other than that, its' the obvious, intuitive, efficient way of doing what you want.

Comment: @Bobaker Madi, when n=1, you don't have to call the function.

Comment: @JB Nizet, you are right I got the answer but I posted the question here to check if any other different ideas. and thank you so much for your suggestion for using StringBuilder
I didn't use this before in my code so I need to read further about it.

Comment: @BobakerMadi, indeed.